# Why WCF service is getting old values of parameters

Tags: wcf, parameter-passing, operationcontract, uritemplate, webinvoke

I have setup two projects. One is WCF service project with following contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
UriTemplate = "xml/{filterName}/{filterValue}")]
XmlElement XMLDataWithFilter(string filterName, string filterValue);
```

Other project uses this WCF service. The values for the parameters `filterName` and `filterValue` sent with first call remain same when some I make call to WCF service with some other parameters.

Why WCF service is retaining the values of parameters?

Comment: Try using tool such as Fiddler to check the parameter values that are passed from the client to the service?

Comment: Can you post the code from your client program that calls the service?